# icarousel class with rotate.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, icarousel

I am developing an iphone app.

I am using the iCarousel class:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

I would like it so that when someone clicks on one of the carousel images, the image flips to show buttons on the back of the image that people can click on.

I am following this tutorial to implement the icarousel class:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/create-an-awesome-carousel-version-2-0/

How can I add methods to achieve the goal I described above?

I did the following:

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.bounds.size.width - 300) / 2.0), 0, 300, 300);

    UIImageView *flipToView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    flipToView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cl2.png"];

    UIView *containerView = self.aCarousel.currentItemView.superview;

    [UIView transitionFromView: containerView toView: flipToView duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:nil];

}
```

but how do I have a different flipped image for each image in the carousel? like the flipped view is different for each image clicked on the carousel. and also how do I hide the flipped image when people scroll to the right?

Comment: Can you post some code What you already tried ? Did you Added any Button Programatically in  `viewForItemAtIndex` method ? if Not then Add A button And Tell What Happens .

Comment: For Fliping the image see the tutorial iphone Flip Image Here: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-FlipImage.html

Comment: how do I reference the image in the carousel to flip it though?

Comment: u can ask @nickloc at his github account by open new issue :S

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra imageview at the center position of the iCarousel as a sibling view via XIB. Initially the alpha of the view is 0 and becomes 1 only when user select any index and then set the image of the imageview according to selected index and just flip it.
And once you have done again set alpha 0.
Try this and if you still face any problem let me know because I have already done this type of thing, not same as flipping but I have implemented the scaling on the iCarousel.